# How to get last record from table SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have problem with receiving last data from table in Android SQLite.

Adding values works great but I struggle with receiving last date from table, here is code:

```
int getKoniec() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sortOrder = TABELA_koniec + " DESC LIMIT 1";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            TABELA,
            new String[] { "koniec" },             
            null,              
            null,          
            null,                  
            null,                   
            sortOrder               
    );

    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    int koniecINT = cursor.getInt(0);
    Log.v("VALUE: ","" + koniecINT);
    cursor.close();

    return koniecINT;
}
```

While adding values 10,9,8,7.. output (return koniecINT) is always 10.
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt return proper value, for example Im adding 
10
9
8
7
and koniecINT return always 10

Comment: What did you expect to get instead, and why?

Comment: Expectation: adding int 10 then call function to receive, result: 10, adding 9 then call function to receive, result: 9.

Comment: It is counter and I need to store data from counter in database

Comment: What did you think `DESC LIMIT 1` means?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674385/sqlite-insertion-order-vs-query-order

Comment: sort the data returned in descending order and the limit of received data is 1

Comment: If I sort the values 10, 9, 8, 7 in descending order and take the first one, I get 10. Why does that surprise you?

Comment: Ok, this was bit stupid. But when Im using good query, the respond is 0.

Comment: There is no first or last row in a table. Add a date/datetime column in the table and use that column to store the order of added rows. Then sort by date desc to get the *last* row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from table_name order by row_id desc limit 1
```

or

```
mCursor.moveToLast();
```

Comment: The max `row_id` is not guaranteed to be the last row inserted: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html Also your 2nd query why do you thing would return the last inserted row?